# Sending Laravel Queue Message Using SQS Amazon

Tags: php, laravel-5, amazon-sqs

I'm using sqs queue in my laravel. Right now I have successsfully pushed my queue job to sqs server as shown in the picture below :
[image]

The problem is, the message is never got executed. So how to process this message on SQS...??
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to run the queue daemon. 
Try to run `php artisan queue:listen` in the project folder.

Comment: Can I use php artisan queue:listen in my elasticbeanstalk server...???
So when I deploy my laravel to live server this Queue still run

Comment: There is no way to run queue daemon on AWS Elastic Beanstalk using supervisor as Laravel documentation recommends, but there is package to move queues tasks to scheduler and then run it using HTTP routes: https://github.com/dusterio/laravel-aws-worker

Comment: Ooow.. Thanks for you info @Anton, I will take a look at your link... :)

Comment: Mmm... My friend said that I can use supervisor, So mm... From your opinion, which one is better Anton ? Using supervisor or aws-worker as you mentioned, aand. Thanks for you info @Anton... :-)

Comment: If there is a possibility to use supervisor, I highly recommend using it, it is much more stable solution :)

Comment: Hay... @Anton... Do you have any example about how to use dusterio/laravel-aws-worker...???